# Using Pytorch's dataloaders & transforms with sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dataset, pytorch

I have been using pytorch a lot and got used to their dataloaders and transforms, in particular when it comes to data augmentation, as they're very user-friendly and easy to understand.

However, I need to run some ML models from sklearn.

Is there a way to use pytorch's dataloaders for sklearn ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. You can do this with `sklearn`'s `partial_fit` method. Read [HERE](https://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/scaling_strategies.html#incremental-learning).

> 6.1.3. **Incremental learning**
>
> Finally, for 3. we have a number of options inside scikit-learn. **Although all algorithms cannot learn
>   incrementally** (i.e. without seeing all the instances at once), **all
>   estimators implementing the partial_fit API are candidates**. Actually,
>   the ability to learn incrementally from a mini-batch of instances
>   (sometimes called “online learning”) is key to out-of-core learning as
>   it guarantees that at any given time there will be only a small amount
>   of instances in the main memory. Choosing a good size for the
>   mini-batch that balances relevancy and memory footprint could involve
>   some tuning [1].

Not all algorithms can do this, however.

Then, you can use `pytorch`'s `dataloader` to preprocess the data and feed it in batches to `partial_fit`.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the [skorch](https://github.com/skorch-dev/skorch) library recently and this could help you.

> "The goal of skorch is to make it possible to use PyTorch with sklearn. "

From the skorch docs:

> class `skorch.dataset.Dataset(X, y=None, length=None)`
> General dataset wrapper that can be used in conjunction with PyTorch DataLoader.

I guess you could use the `Dataset` class for wrapping your PyTorch `DataLoader` and use sklearn models. If you would like to use other PyTorch features like PyTorch Tensors you could also do that.